# Internet checker with alert dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to do a task where check the internet and then alert the user using an alertdialog using a connectivity manager.. does anybody know how I would implement this in my main activity when both my buttons are pressed ( separately)?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
  Button login, register;

   @Override
   protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_bt);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_bt);
    login.setOnClickListener(this);
    register.setOnClickListener(this);

}


    @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent i = null;
        if (v.getId() == login.getId()) {
        i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (v.getId() == register.getId()) {
        i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class `CustomClickListener` :

```
class CustomClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(isOnline()) {
            Intent i = null;
            i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RegistrationActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the `OnCreate` method :

```
login.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener());
register.setOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener());
```

This method checks for Internet connection :

```
protected boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But how would that check if theres an internet connection when the buttons clicked?

Answer (score 0):

> Check for internet connection

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean connected=ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
    if(connected){
        //network connected
    }else{
        //network disconnected
    }
```

> Manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```